# How to get a value from one select list based on value selected from another list in Symfony2?

Tags: php, jquery, symfony, twig

When I select a member from a Member list I need to get his default department from another select Department list on 'Add new member' form and, if necessary to change this member's department affiliation for a selected committee.

I have two entities, Member and Dept. Dept is also a property in Member entity. Both drop down lists are filled form the database.

In the FormType.php file I have:

```
class CommMemberType extends AbstractType

    /**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('member','entity', array(
                'label' => 'Member Name',
                'empty_value' => ' ',
                'class' => 'CommitteesBundle:Member',
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('m')
                        ->orderBy('m.fname', 'ASC');
                },
            )
        )

        ->add('dept', 'entity', array(
            'label' => 'Department',
            'empty_value' => '---Select Department---',
            'required' => true,
            'class' => 'CommitteesBundle:Lookup\Dept',
            'property' => 'meaning',
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('dept')
                    ->orderBy('dept.meaning', 'ASC');
            },
        ));
```

Unfortunately, I was not able to find any solution for using jQuery to solve this problem. Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it requires a little bit of boilerplate.

Firstly, you need to add two events to your form `FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA` and `FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT` to fill dependant drop-down with relevant options when the form is submitted or entity is set.

In the example below departure dates depends on chosen trip.

```
class ExampleType extends AbstractType
{
   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
   {
        $builder->add('tripsFk', 'entity', array(
            'class'         => 'ExampleBundle:Trips',
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('t')
                        ->orderBy('t.id', 'DESC');
            },
            'label'       => 'Trip',
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'booking_trip'
            )
        ));

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, array($this, 'onPreSetData'));
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, array($this, 'onPreSubmit'));

    }

    function onPreSubmit(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $data = $event->getData();

        $trip = $data['tripsFk'];
        $this->populateChoices($form, $trip);
    }

    function onPreSetData(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $entity = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();


        $tripId = $entity->getTripsFk() ? $entity->getTripsFk() : null;

        $this->populateChoices($form, $tripId);
    }

    public function populateChoices($form, $tripId)
    {
        $form->add('departIdFk', 'entity', array(
            'label'         => 'Departure Code',
            'class'         => 'ExampleBundle:Departures',
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($tripId) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('t')
                        ->andWhere('t.trip_id', ':trip_id')
                        ->setParameter('trip_id', $tripId);
            },
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'booking_date'
            )
        ));
    }
}
```

The next thing you have to do is write a javascript that will change `.booking_date` drown down options on trip change. In the js snippet below on `.booking_trip` change event  we remove existing departures options, and load the new ones:

```
var bookingTripChange = (function () {
        var $trip = $('.booking_trip');
        var $dates = $('.booking_date');


        init = function () {
            $trip.on('change', function () {

                $dates.attr('disabled', 'disabled');

                $.ajax({
                    url: Routing.generate('load_departures', {tripId: $trip.val()}),
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (response) {
                        $dates.find('option').remove();

                        $("<option/>", {value: '', text: 'Specify Departure Code'}).appendTo($dates);

                        $.each(response.tripdates, function (index, entity) {
                            $("<option/>", {value: entity.id, text: entity.label}).appendTo($dates);
                        });

                        $dates.removeAttr('disabled');

                    }
                });
            });
        };
        return {
            init: init
        };
    })();

bookingTripChange.init();
```

The last thing do to is to write an action for `load_departures` route. It could be a simple select with given `$tripId` and hydrated to `array`.

```
public function loadChoicesAction(Request $request, $tripId)
{
        $tripdates = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('ExampleBundle:Departures')
            ->getTripsDatesOptions($tripId);



        $content = json_encode(array(
            'tripdates' => $tripdates
        ));

        $reponse = new Response($content, 200);

        return $reponse;
}
```

P.S.

1. to make js routing work you need to install: [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle)

Comment: Thank you very much! It definitely helps!